# Pandas read_excel skips end-zeros in float column

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a lot of Excel files where a column supposed to be a string unfortunately was saved as a float and now `pd.read_excel` skips end-zeroes and reads '18.10' as 18.1 i.e.. I tried options `dtype='object'` and to specify that this column is a string, but every time `pd.read_excel` reads it as 18.1. However when I load it to google sheets I can see '18.10'. One way to solve my problem is to save all these files as csv by hand in Google Sheets, however there are more than hundred of them and I hope there exists another solution. What can I do?

Comment: `read_excel` does work properly. There is no difference between `18.1` and `18.10` if you want to treat this as numeric column. If you still want to preserve then trailing zeros, Convert the column into object then write the file so that the 0 will be preserved.

Comment: It's simply rounding. As said by @MohamedThasinah a trailing 0 in a decimal makes no difference. But you can format the number column to have 2 decimal places